# Can we create tables in PGADMIN4 without specifying the datatype's length?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

I am new to PostgresSQL and using pgadmin4 on my Windows machine, While creating tables came across datatypes like- `char` and `char[]` and also `char Varying` and `char Varying[]`.

I want to know is there a method by which I can create an attribute name specifying the datatype but not length?

Comment: `character varying` (or `varchar`) doesn't require a length limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the datatype like `char` or `varchar` will do the work you want to do

Answer (score 0):

Yes: use the `text` data type. It performs just as well and has no length limit (there is an absolute size limit of 1GB though).